# Is this form of downvoting valid?

Tags: discussion

I often visit room number 17 in the chat - the famous JavaScript room, blessed with 10 million room owners.

I have learned JavaScript there from a total n00b level to an intermediate one. And now, when some other users come to ask questions, and I can answer it, I help that guy. He says thank you, and lives happily ever-after.

For fun, I often drop the following line after someone says thankyou to me:

> No problem.... Feel free to upvote any of my answers on the main site to show gratitude. (j/k)

*The `(j/k)` is an obligatory part that I never miss.*

So another regular user in the chat room (not the one to whom I said that) got annoyed (maybe) by this. And wrote the following:

> @AwalGarg: From now on, every time you say that "feel free to upvote any of answers on the main site to show gratitude ;-)", Imma downvote something of yours.

And after that, I received 3 downvotes, and 2 useless edit suggestions.

meh, I don't care about those. I am not even sure that those downvotes were related to that message or not...
**But just asking outta curiosity, is this form of downvoting valid?**

Comment: Ah. I see that the Lounge is no longer the most notorious room. Seems like we've got some catching up to do...

Comment: @Mysticial Hahaha, The JS room is not much notorious. That user is also good who posted that downvote message. I am not reporting any notorious behavior, just want to know that is this form of downvoting valid?

Comment: If it's one user downvoting all your stuff, then that's serial voting and is a suspendable offense. But more often then not, it's multiple people from the same chatroom coming to the same post and voting on it (up or down). In our room, we call it "getting lounged". That sort of voting *is* valid and is no different from getting linked on meta or reddit.

Comment: (I think I missed the better question [first](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/17?m=19693097#19693097), is [_that_](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/17?m=19693171#19693171) form of upvoting [valid?](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/17?m=19693206#19693206)... maybe it [was](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/17?m=19693255#19693255))

Comment: @Mysticial all the downvotes are on different posts. Is that still that sort of voting?

Comment: Not sure why this is getting downvotes... just asked if this is valid or not. What is bad in that? I thought meta votes represent agreement/disagreement...

Comment: What about a [just-kidding](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/just-kidding) tag? (j/k)

Comment: As @Mysticial said, it's valid. In our room, we call it "The Tavern effect"

Comment: Consider also, that not everyone here are native English speakers, and they may not know what "j/k" is.

Answer (score 27):

This form of begging for rep (no the "j/k" makes no difference) isn't really valid. If you wrote the same on the main site I'd flag your comment or edit it out of your post.

Revenge donvoting also isn't "valid", but you have no proof that the person who wrote that comment was the person who did the downvoting. If it was then it might be picked up by the serial-vote-reversal script.

In short, you both might be at "fault".

However, you have the opportunity to be the better person. Stop telling your "joke". It's irrelevant to the help you've provided. The help you provided in chat, where there's no chance of getting rep. If you want rep for your help, post on the man site.

Comment: I _know_ that the person who wrote that comment did _not_ downvote. Just that his message went into the star queue getting exposure to more visitors... And I don't get votes like that.

Comment: It doesn't matter whether you actually get votes @awal; do you see why it might not be appropriate? You're doing a good job completely selflessly (no rep in chat) helping people. Don't spoil it afterwards for a "joke".

Comment: @ben +1 for that comment (not a j/k)

Comment: @Ben I completely agree with you on that ;)

Comment: _"If you wrote the same on the main site I'd flag your"_ I know the main site is not for jokes :) One can joke in a chat room though.

Answer (score 6):

First of all, I would suggest that convert your statement

> No problem.... Feel free to upvote any of my answers on the main site to show gratitude. (j/k)

to just a

> Thankyou

if you can,

---

Your statement is not offensive by any means but yet I gotta feeling that **asking for votes(you are not but it seems like) by yourself is a thing which will not be much liked**.Just concentrate on giving useful,to the point accurate answers. The one who will find your answer useful will upvote your answer by themselves.and the thing you are saying about downvoting,let the [automatic processes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28756/what-can-i-do-if-im-the-victim-of-serial-downvoting) of Stack Overflow handle them.

Comment: I agree with you, even more And who is to say that some new user feels it is ok to do that and upvotes randomly.